Setting a Form DataSet Value without OnChange Event
I am working on an edit form that I need some help figuring out how to automatically set a value on.  The initial values are set from an API call to our DB.
Here is the situation. The form allow the user to change the "Type" of the item from a dropdown, which sets the typeId to a value of 1-5.  If initially item had a typeId of 5, the form does not display the Toggle Switch or Radio Group, because the item would not have a set value ("null") for those fields.  Once a user changes the type to something other than 5, the fields get displayed.
If the user changes the type to typeId of 1-4 the input fields will be displayed, so I would like to automatically set the correctable to "0" and tagCriteria to "1000". As it is right now, the user has to toggle the switch or select a different radio button in order to trigger the onChange event to set the values, otherwise the values are not set. But, I just want these to be the initial values, that can still be changed if the user changes the value vi that toggle or selected a different radio button. Can someone help me figure out a way to set those values automatically?
HERE IS MY BASIC FORM AND INPUT CHANGE
const [values, setValues] = React.useState({} as any);

const handleInputChange = e => {
  const { name, value } = e.target;
  setValues({
    ...values,
    [name]: value // allows value as typed
  });
};


<form>
 <Input
    type='text'
    onChange={handleInputChange}
    name='name'
    label='Name'
    value={values.name}
    error={errors.name}
 />
 <Dropdown
    onChange={handleInputChange}
    label='Type'
    name='typeId'
    value={values.typeId}
    prompt='Select A Type...'
    url={TypesURL}
  />
 {(() => {
  if (values.typeId != 5) {
  <ToggleSwitch
      onChange={handleInputChange}
      label1='No'
      label2='Yes'
      name='correctable'      
      defaultValue=0
      value={values.correctable}
   />
   <RadioGroup
      onChange={handleInputChange}
      items={radioItems}
      name='tagCriteria'
      defaultValue='1000'
      value={values.tagCriteria}
  />
 }
 })()}  

</form>

Ultimately, I eventually need to set the values to 'correctable = 0, tagCriteria =  null' and the tagCriteria Radio Group would be disabled. This is because if the item is not correctable (0), then it has no tag criteria. Then when the user toggles correctable to 1, then Radio Group would become enabled and the tagCriteria value would automatically set to a default of "1000", but if I can just find a way to get both just set to a default, I am sure I could figure out the rest.

It sounds like you want to automatically set values in your form when a user changes the typeId from 5 to another value (1-4). To achieve this, you can use a useEffect hook that watches for changes in the typeId state and updates the values of correctable and tagCriteria accordingly
React.useEffect(() => {
  if (values.typeId && values.typeId >= 1 && values.typeId <= 4) {
     setValues(prevValues => ({
        ...prevValues,
        correctable: 0,
        tagCriteria: '1000',
     }));
  } else if (values.typeId === '5') {
     setValues(prevValues => ({
       ...prevValues,
       correctable: null,
       tagCriteria: null,
      }));
 }
}, [values.typeId]);

This approach should automatically set and manage the values based on the user’s interaction with the dropdown without additional user input. Let me know if this helps or if you need further assistance!

This is doing exactly what I was hoping for it to do.  I tried only setting correctable to 0 when the type was changed from 5 and adding another if where if typeId was not 5 and correctable was 1 to set the tagCriteria to '1000' (only setting the tag criteris if the items is actually correctable), but it never seemed to set the value.  Got any clues?

The issue might be that state updates in React are asynchronous, so when you update correctable, the useEffect may not immediately catch the change to set tagCriteria. You need to watch both typeId and correctable together in the useEffect to ensure they work as expected.


without OnChange Event

but...

If the user changes the type to typeId of 1-4 the input fields will be displayed, so I would like to automatically set the correctable to "0" and tagCriteria to "1000".

So the change event is already occurring.  Here:
 <Dropdown
   onChange={handleInputChange}
   label='Type'
   name='typeId'
   value={values.typeId}
   prompt='Select A Type...'
   url={TypesURL}
/>

If, when the user makes this change, you want to perform an operation then you would perform that operation in this function:
const handleInputChange = e => {
  const { name, value } = e.target;
  setValues({
    ...values,
    [name]: value // allows value as typed
  });
};

For example, if you want to set specific values when name is 'typeId' and value is in the range of 1 through 4 then it might look something like this:
const handleInputChange = e => {
  const { name, value } = e.target;
  const newValues = {
    ...values,
    [name]: value
  };
  if (name === 'typeId' && [1,2,3,4].includes(value)) {
    newValues.correctable = 0;
    newValues.tagCriteria = '1000';
  }
  setValues(newValues);
};

Basically, your goal to not use onChange seems a bit misguided when you want this operation to take place when the user changes the typeId value.  Simply set those default values when that happens.

As a potential alternative, you could also just set those defaults initially in the state:
const [values, setValues] = React.useState({
  correctable: 0,
  tagCriteria: '1000'
} as any);

